# Laravel storage outside on localmachine in folder like as 'C:/uploads'

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, storage, file-system-storage

I want to save file in folder outside Laravel project to folder on local machine for example 'C:/uploads'. When the project installed on local machine is saved in 'C:/uploads' folder but when the project is installed online on server don't save in 'C:/uploads'.

In filesystems.php I put like as:

```
'local' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
      //'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
      //'root' => public_path('uploads'),
      'root'=>'C:\uploads',
 ],

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
     'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

In HomeController.php function:

```
$files = Input::file('images');
$file_count = count($files);
$uploadcount = 0;        
foreach($files as $file) {
  //$destinationPath = 'uploads';
  $filename = time() .'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
  //$file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, File::get($file));
  $image=new Image();
  $image->sparepart_id = $id;
  $image->Filename=$filename;
  $image->save();
  $uploadcount ++;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's [environment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration) variables to achieve this.

In your .env file (example 1)

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=name_of_your_disk
```

Or define the application environment (example 2)

```
APP_ENV=production
```

Then change these values accordingly for your local env and server env and use them in your code to check what env is being used.

In your home controller you can simply use the Storage facade without the disk call to use the default disk defined in ex 1. Or you could check for APP_ENV and save or not save to the desired disk based on that.

```
if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'production')
{
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, File::get($file))
}
```

Comment: For example 1  I rename my disc with 'data' (E:) and put in FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=data  then say 'Driver [data] not supported' and for example 2 don't save file in folder on PC disk partition

Comment: FILESYSTEM_DRIVER is not the actual driver, but an environment variable that is used by default in config/filesystems to define the NAME of your default filesystem disk. You should use 'data' as the name of the disk and 'local' as the driver of that same disk.